# how to think of probabilies or probability distributions for events like death

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

This is a bit more philosophical question regarding probabilities.

If we would like to find the probability of smokers, sex groups, etc, this is a pretty simple thing to do. All we do is count all smokers and divide it by the total population of smokers and non-smokers. As well we can do the same for finding the probability of sex. We just count all the men and divide by the total number of men and women.

On the other side, I have been thinking about events you can not count, but still, we treat them as probabilities. To me, it looks like a paradox and I was motivated by the nowadays popular question of probabilities of death given COVID-19.

But let's just ignore COVID-19, let's just think of the probability of death, as a marginal probability. How could we possibly think of it? You can not just count the number of dead people in the population of alive people. This will always be zero. This kind of probability would thereof always need to be conditioned on something. For example time period.

So how to think of a probability like that on an intuitive level? How to define it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probability of death is $1$; we all eventually die. However, the probability of death within a certain time frame (perhaps the next $5$ years) is not $1$.

We can certainly count how many people died in the past $5$ years and use this to estimate the probability that a randomly chosen person will die in the next $5$ years.

To answer your question, you need to put some kind of constraint on your death. We need to ask questions like ''What is the probability of a person dying in the next $T$ years?''. This can obviously be extended to things like ''What is the probability of death in the next $T$ years, given the person is a smoker?''.

More generally, you should look at the field of [Survival Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis).